# How to keep slider images proportionate when responsive?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a slider on the homepage and other large hero images on other static pages. All 100% screen width. On smaller screens the other hero images stay larger (height wise) than my slider images. All images heights are set to auto.

I need the slider images to not just scale based on full width. I don't care if they get cut-off, the image heights are becoming too small on mobile. It seems the difference is the background-size: cover and the padding. But when I try it it doesn't work the same, I'm either putting it on the wrong element or it's messing with it because the slider width is 500%?

The hero images are built like this:

```
    <div class="hero" style="background-image: url('/images/static/shop/hero_necklaces.jpg');">
                    <div class="hero-text">
                        <h1>Jewelry</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

    @media (max-width: 480px)
    .hero {
     padding-top: 60px;
     padding-bottom: 60px;
    }

      @media (max-width: 650px)
      .hero {
      padding-top: 90px;
      padding-bottom: 90px;
      }

    .hero {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 140px;
    display: table;
     vertical-align: middle;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    }
```

The slider is built like this:

```
     <div id="captioned-gallery" class="homepage-slider">
       <figure class="slider">
         <figure>
           <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry"><img               src="${request.contextPath}/images/static/home/header_hero1.jpg" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection"></a>
        <!--<figcaption class="hero-text">Sample Text 1</figcaption>-->
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/joinUs.jsp"><img src="${request.contextPath}/images/static/home/header_hero2.jpg" alt="Get Paid to Share the Hope"></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/impact.jsp"><img src="${request.contextPath}/images/static/home/header_hero3.jpg" alt="Handcrafted Artisan Made"></a>
      </figure>
       <figure>
        <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry"><img src="${request.contextPath}/images/static/home/header_hero1.jpg" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection"></a>
       </figure>
      </figure>
     </div>


    div#captioned-gallery {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
           }
    .homepage-slider {
            padding-bottom: 115px;
           }
     figure { margin: 0; }
      @-webkit-keyframes slidy { 
        0%  { left: 0%; }
        20% { left: 0%; }
        25% { left: -100%; }
        45% { left: -100%; }
        50% { left: -200%; }
        70% { left: -200%; } 
        75% { left: -300%; }
        100% { left: -300%; } 
        }
     @keyframes slidy { 
        0%  { left: 0%; }
        20% { left: 0%; }
        25% { left: -100%; }
        45% { left: -100%; }
        50% { left: -200%; }
        70% { left: -200%; } 
        75% { left: -300%; }
        100% { left: -300%; } 
       }
   figure.slider {
      position: relative;
      width: 500%;
      font-size: 0;
      -webkit-animation: 40s slidy infinite;
      animation: 40s slidy infinite;
     }
    figure.slider figure { 
       width: 20%;
       height: auto;
       display: inline-block;
       position: inherit;
     }
     figure.slider img {
       width: 100%;
        height: auto;
       margin: 0px;
      }
```

Comment: What is the logic behind making an object of width 500% ?

Comment: http://thenewcode.com/627/Make-A-Responsive-CSS3-Image-Slider

Answer (score 0):

The slider seems to work fine, other than a long pause at the end.  I've adjusted the width of the slider to 400%, each slide to 25%, and the animation.  I'm guessing that the slider originally had 5 slides in it (4 with the first repeated at the end), and you didn't adjust for it.

```css
div#captioned-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.homepage-slider {
  padding-bottom: 115px;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  63.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  96.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  63.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  96.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
figure.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slidy infinite;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
}
figure.slider figure {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit;
}
figure.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery" class="homepage-slider">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/000ff0" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection">
      </a>
      <!--<figcaption class="hero-text">Sample Text 1</figcaption>-->
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/joinUs.jsp">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/0ff000" alt="Get Paid to Share the Hope">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/impact.jsp">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/00ff00" alt="Handcrafted Artisan Made">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/000ff0" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection">
      </a>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

If you want the slider images to be "taller" on mobile, gradually as the screen sizes shrinks, then my suggestion would be to increase the size of the .slider object using a combination of calc on width and margin left (margin left half the difference of width), and add overflow:hidden on .home-page-slider.

If you don't mind a sudden shift, at say 600px width or less, then just make the margin left -10% and width 120% at that beakpoint on the img like this:

```css
div#captioned-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.homepage-slider {
  padding-bottom: 115px;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  63.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  96.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  63.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  96.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
figure.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slidy infinite;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
}
figure.slider figure {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit;
  overflow:hidden;
}
figure.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px)
{
  figure.slider img { width: 120%; margin-left: -10%; margin-right: -10% }
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery" class="homepage-slider">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/000ff0" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection">
      </a>
      <!--<figcaption class="hero-text">Sample Text 1</figcaption>-->
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/joinUs.jsp">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/0ff000" alt="Get Paid to Share the Hope">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/impact.jsp">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/00ff00" alt="Handcrafted Artisan Made">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/000ff0" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection">
      </a>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Smooth:

```css
div#captioned-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.homepage-slider {
  padding-bottom: 115px;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  63.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  96.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  33.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  63.33% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  66.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  96.66% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  99.99% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -300%;
  }
}
figure.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 400%;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slidy infinite;
  animation: 10s slidy infinite;
}
figure.slider figure {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  figure.slider img {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% + ((600px - 100%) / 5));
    width: calc(100% + ((600px - 100%) / 5));
    margin-left: -webkit-calc(10% - 60px);
    margin-left: calc(10% - 60px);
    margin-right: -webkit-calc(10% - 60px);
    margin-right: calc(10% - 60px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery" class="homepage-slider">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/000ff0" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection">
      </a>
      <!--<figcaption class="hero-text">Sample Text 1</figcaption>-->
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/joinUs.jsp">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/0ff000" alt="Get Paid to Share the Hope">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/jsp/static/impact.jsp">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/00ff00" alt="Handcrafted Artisan Made">
      </a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <a href="${request.contextPath}/category/Jewelry">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1280x600/000ff0" alt="The 2015 Fall Collection">
      </a>
    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I just followed the slider instructions here and there is meant to be the same image at beginning and end for "smooth loop". http://thenewcode.com/627/Make-A-Responsive-CSS3-Image-Slider

Comment: Do you mind giving an example of calc on width and margin left?

Comment: The second example shows how to do to the sudden shift technique.  Try it and see if that works for you.  That is how most places do it since it is the most cross-browser compatible, although most browsers support calc now. An example width would be say.. `calc(100%+((600px-100vw)/5))` at the 600px breakpoint (or less) and `calc(0-((600px-100vw)/10))` for the margin-left.

Comment: It doesn't look any taller under 600px and now there's a gap with the image and page on the right, it doesn't span full width of screen. It's supposed to have margin-left and margin-right at 10%?  You keep mentioning only margin-left as relevant?

Comment: I have 3 sets of answers, the first is mostly original code, the second is with sudden shift at 600px, the third is with smooth transition to slightly taller image.

Comment: As per your smooth loop, they have 4 distinct images, with 5 total.  You have 3 distinct images, with 4 total (first repeated at end), so you need to recalculate the .slider width to 400%, the .slider figure to 25%, and the animation needs to be changed (I've done all that for you).

Comment: Thank you. I've copied and pasted in your code examples. The last one works best as far as image doesn't have big gap on the right side between the browser window and the image, but none of them make the slider images any taller than the original code did.

Comment: They definitely should be taller, by about 10% or so on 360px wide screens.  Can increase that more if you like.  What browser are you looking at it in?

Comment: I've updated the 3rd one again to make it even larger at small sizes.  So large that it doesn't actually shrink anymore once you get below 600px widths anymore.

Comment: If you are looking at it in an old android browser (4.4.4 or earlier -- which is almost all of them), that would probably be a problem as the android browser is by far the worst of the major ones and doesn't support calc.  Use chrome on android instead.